# Identifying hashtable as a userdefined type in OCaml

Tags: types, ocaml

I want to be able to define a type (say my_type) which can identify hashtables with strings as keys and mapped to integer values.
So, I tried

```
# type my_type = (string, int) Hashtbl.t;;
```

But, when I try

```
# let a = Hashtbl.create 100;;
val a : ('_a, '_b) Hashtbl.t = <abstr>
# Hashtbl.add a "A" 12;;
- : unit = ()
# a;;
- : (string, int) Hashtbl.t = <abstr>
```

The last line shows (string, int) Hashtbl.t = abstr instead of my_type. How can I make sure it gives me the type of the hashtable as my_type?

Answer (score 9):

It makes no sense to declare type synonyms and to expect the compiler to use either one expression or the other in precise situations: as they are equal types, the compiler will use either one and you have little control on that.

If you want to enforce type abstraction, so as to not mix a type `my_type` with any other `(string, int) Hashtbl.t`, you should define a new type with a constructor marking the difference:

```
type my_type = Tbl of (string, int) Hashtbl.t
let a = Tbl (Hashtbl.create 100)
let add (Tbl t) k v = Hashtbl.add t k v
```

You may want this (and pay the cost of having to transform all values of `my_type` into hashtables by explicit pattern-matching when you want to use one of the `Hashtbl` function), or you may want to manipulate only a type synonym, but in the latter case you should not expect the compiler output to report any particular type.

Comment: As of OCaml 3.11 you can use "private type abbreviations" to get a new type without runtime overhead (I never checked this myself). For that you would use `type my_type = private (string, int) Hashtbl.t`. Inside the defining module `my_type` is just a plain type abbreviation. Outside however, you need explicit conversion functions. For one direction also coercions work, e.g., `t :> (string, int) Hashtbl.t` to coerce `t` of type `my_type` into a hash table.

Comment: @chris: But this suppose a module abstraction, outside which you have only one side of the conversion. What would be needed here is an "opaque type abbreviation" that allows *both* conversion directions but enforces them to be explicit, as "private" does compared to usual synonyms.

Answer (score 2):

Update: sorry, as gasche points out, you can use a simple type annotation to do that, forget about the type coercion

```
# type my_type = (string, int) Hashtbl.t;;
type my_type = (string, int) Hashtbl.t
# let (a : my_type) = Hashtbl.create 100;;
val a : my_type = <abstr>
```

Comment: This is not a very good suggestion: it is not about subtyping here, but simply two types that are equal. Coercions doesn't make much sense, as a simple type annotation would do, and in fact even a type annotation is of little use.

Comment: You are right, I forgot about type annotation.. This is indeed not a good advice..

Answer (score 1):

`my_type` is just a synonym for `(string, int) Hashtbl.t`, you can use both interchangeably.

You can tell the compiler that `a` is of type `my_type`, and get nicer output, this way:

```
# let (a:my_type) = Hashtbl.create 100;;
val a : my_type = <abstr>
# a;;
- : my_type = <abstr>
```

If you're wondering about `<abstr>`, it means that the toplevel doesn't know how to print `a` (its content, not its type).